# What is the reason behind this strange censorship of a specific scene in Tokyo Ghoul?

Tags: anime-production, tokyo-ghoul, censorship

During the scene where Kurona and Nashiro are fighting Juzo in Season 2 Episode 4, I noticed some censorship. Juzo ends up stabbing Kurona a lot with his knives, but it's blurred out like this:

> [image].

I thought this was really strange seeing as the series has shown far worse, such as torture and other extremely gory deaths. Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: Season one was also extremely censored in the violent scenes, with a intense blurry darkness covering many of the gory scenes.

Comment: Was it? I guess I never noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole show was highly censored, as shown in this comparison album (Obviously spoilers):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpjaQ.jpg

The main reason is Japanese censorship laws, which are very different from laws in the West, but some people have mentioned that S2 was airing at the same time as some ISIS attacks took place, thus this might have something to do with TV networks censoring knives.

Comment: What is the relationship between ISIS and knives, that would explain this?

Comment: https://www.rt.com/news/225763-isis-execute-japanese-hostage/ , Ep. 4 should've aired around the same time.

Answer (score -3):

I was told that the reason there was censorship in Tokyo Ghoul was because if it wasn't censored, it would have brought the rating up to 18+. You have to remember, in certain scenes with body parts, there'd be veins, muscle, etc and others like the knife scene, well, it might have been censored because of the cruelty in having several knives stabbing you at once. They might see this scene worst than other like the torturing of Kaneki because we never actually saw his toes and fingers cut off, only the blood (and Kaneki's screaming). If you think I'm wrong, I understand that and sorry if I've offended anyone.

Comment: Who told you this and what makes this show any different from other shows with similar violence? If you can't cite a source, then it's just heresay rather than an answer backed by facts.